# How to convert file separator in maven

Tags: java, maven-2, glassfish

I have a property defined like this:

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

Since I use Windows as OS, it contains backslashes. I want to add this path to a glassfish domain as JVM option (using glassfish maven plugin). The problem is, that asadmin can consume only slash as separator, and all my backslashes keep on disappearing. How can I define a property with exactly the same content with slashes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is a non-programmatical way to do that. So I suggest a groovy one-liner with the [Maven GMaven plugin](http://gmaven.codehaus.org/Executing+Groovy+Code) (GMaven is usually the simplest way to embed programmatic code into a pom):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>setproperty</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
pom.properties['main.basedir']=project.parent.basedir.absolutePath.replace('\\','/');
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Oh hell. I dont even know what the hell happened, but I started to receive error for exactly the same stuff you suggested: [INFO] groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.absolutePath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. Nothing is changed and not working anymore

Comment: my mistake. it's either `absolutePath` without parentheses or `getAbsolutePath()`. fixed my code

Comment: yep. Now it works. Then the only thing I dont know, how it was look like working earlier :D. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: Really nice way to hack the POM. +1

Comment: We had a problem where this solution didn't work for different developers. We end up replacing `'\\','/'` with `File.separator,'/'`. 
In case anyone else has the problem we had, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596884/using-groovy-in-pom-file-for-delimiter-switching-works-differently-for-different)

Comment: Is this still the best way as of 2021?

Answer (score 3):

Just an update to Sean's answer, I have had to make some minor adjustments in order to adapt it to the latest groovy maven plugin version:

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
              <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>setproperty</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
        project.properties['basedir']=project.parent.basedir.absolutePath.replace('\\','/');
                        </source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```