# maven basedir - replace backslash with frontslash

Tags: java, maven

How could I replace my basedir, with one \, to a basedir with \\?

I've tried:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                <version>6</version>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ecad-application-ws-webservice</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>ecad-application-ws-webservice.war</bundleFileName>
                        <contextRoot>/ecad-ws/ecadservice</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>

               <source>
                    project.properties['basedir']=project.properties['basedir'].replace('\\','/');
               </source>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but that doesn't change anything.. Anyone got some other ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to replace that? This is java there shouldn't be a problem with that?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using it in a jboss-as-maven plugin to run an sql script for the h2mem datasource. I need the ${basedir} var because this plugin is defined in an ear module and should, therefor, not contain resources (otherwise I could have used classpath:scripts/create.sql).                                     <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM ${basedir}/src/scripts/create.sql;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url> and I forgot.. the ${basedir} results in a string without slashes in that plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used to groovy plugin to solve it :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>set-unixy_build_directory!</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>execute</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <classpath>
                    <element>
                      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                      <version>2.4</version>
                     </element>
                  </classpath>
                  <source>
                    if (org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
                      project.properties.myDynamicProperty =
                      project.basedir.absolutePath.replace('\\','\\\\');
                    }
                  </source>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Or project.basedir = project.basedir.replace('\\', '\\\\'); replace() method returns a new String. You have to set project.basedir to this new String.

Answer (score 1):

Can you See if the following works?

Replace

project.properties['basedir']=project.properties['basedir'].replace('\','/');

with

pom.properties['main.basedir']=project.parent.basedir.absolutePath.replace('\','/');

Comment: Doesn't work. The basedir doesn't get replaced. It stays without slashes. (RUNSCRIPT FROM C:JAVADEVELOPMENTWORKSPACESECAD2ECAD2APPLICATIONWSEAR/SRC/SCRIPTS/CREATE.SQL ) and that should be: RUNSCRIPT FROM C:/JAVADEVELOPMENT/WORKSPACES/ECAD2/ECAD2/APPLICATIONWS/EAR/SRC/SCRIPTS/CREATE.SQL

Comment: Ok. Then check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596884/using-groovy-in-pom-file-for-delimiter-switching-works-differently-for-different

Comment: Doesn't change anything. It looks to me that the basedir just isn't changed.. Is this the correct way to do it..?